# How to get immediate value /current value of paper-slider on change event or immediate value change event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer

i am trying to change the background color of div on change function of paper slider with slider's current value but failed to get value of slider i have tried on-immediate-value-change or on-change function ,but i don't know how to get current value of paper-slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way i know of to get the value of a slider is to assign it a declarative variable and use that in your javascript.

example

```
 <paper-slider min="0" max="100" value="{{sliderValue}}" on-change="{{sliderChange}}"></paper-slider>
```

then in js

```
sliderChange: function () {
  var value = this.sliderValue;
  // do something with value
}
```

plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/gihpf5aZH4obhquaDtZQ?p=preview

edit: original post using event sender value returned the value of the beginning of the event and not the end value

Answer (score 7):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-slider), there are two different kinds of value for the `paper-slider`:

- `value` *The number that represents the current value.*
- `immediateValue` *The immediate value of the slider. This value is updated while the user is dragging the slider.*

One can access these properties directly on the `paper-slider` element.

While the user drags the slider, a first event is fired continuously: `immediate-value-change`.
When the user stops dragging the slider, two other events are fired: `change` and `value-change`. The difference between the two is that the `change` event is only fired on user's interaction.

Considering these informations, you may add to your host element the following snippets (your slider should have a `slider` id, but you can obviously change that):

```
listeners: {
    'immediate-value-change': 'immediateValueChangeHandler',
    'change': 'changeHandler'
},

immediateValueChangeHandler: function (e) {
    var value = this.$.slider.immediateValue;
    // do something
},

changeHandler: function (e) {
    var value = this.$.slider.value;
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest listening to the change event and then accessing the srcElement.value to get the current value

```
sliderElement.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.type, e.srcElement.value);
  });
```